# Using Azure Devops: How to add a table

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm new to Azure DevOps but my company has moved over to it from Jira.
I've googled it and checked with ChatGPT on how to add a table to a ticket description and all the sources seem to say that I should use the [markdown approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#tables).

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   Cell   |   Cell   |   Cell   |
|   Cell   |   Cell   |   Cell   |
```

but when I attempt this, the table doesn't render on saving.
How should I be doing this instead. There doesn't seem to be a direct answer for this.

I was expecting a full table to render as in other systems.
However the text remains unchanged and unedited.

Comment: The article that you link to is about the wiki service within Azure DevOps. Are you editing a wiki entry, using the markdown widget, and markdown is not working in the widget?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't say anything about work items (you are probably incorrectly calling them "tickets"; please learn and use the correct terminology for the platform to prevent confusion). Work items **do not** fully support markdown, although some markdown features such as code snippets work.

They also, unfortunately, don't readily support creating tables. You can copy and paste a table from a different tool such a Word, but you can't natively create a table within the work item editor. Ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-it-easy-to-insert-tables-into-a-work-item-des/1108159

Markdown support is available in preview *for comments* as of a few months ago, although I haven't tried it out and can provide no further guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-222-update#azure-boards-1